# for loop in kernel function causes "unspecific launch failure" error

Tags: c++, cuda

when I using a for loop which contains large numbers of cycles, the error "unspecific launch failure"will occur.
my code is as followed:

```
//Kernel function
__global__ void Kernel(double *M_gpu, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        M_gpu[i] = i / 2 + 6;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    //Allocating CPU space
    int size = 10000000;
    double *M = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    //Allocating GPU space
    double *M_gpu;
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&M_gpu, sizeof(double)*size); 
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) 
    { 
        cout << "Allocating CPU space failed！" << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus) << endl; getchar(); exit(0);
    }
    //calling Kernel function
    Kernel << <1, 1 >> > (M_gpu, size);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError(); 
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) 
    { 
        cout << "Calling Kernel function failed！" << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus) << endl; getchar(); exit(0);
    }
    //copying data from GPU to CPU
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(M, M_gpu, sizeof(double)*size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) 
    { 
        cout << "Copying data from GPU to CPU failed！" << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus) << endl; getchar(); exit(0);
    }
    //END
    cout << "Success!" << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

My operating system is Win10 64bit and my GPU is GTX860M with 4GB memory and my CUDA version is 8.0. I using Visual Studio 2015 community.
I know it is not good to do something like that because it performs badly. But I just want to know what is wrong with the code above,it seems good logically and it can be certain of no memory allocating error occurred. is there some limitations to kernel function?

Comment: You may be running into a windows WDDM TDR timeout.  On windows for a GPU in WDDM mode (which yours will be), kernels are limited to about 2 seconds of execution time.  Beyond that, windows will reset the GPU and you may see a message "the display driver stopped responding ..." in the windows system tray.  The CUDA kernel itself has been terminated at that point, and the CUDA error code can be one of several, including the one you mention.  Also, please don't put in pictures of your code, please copy and paste the code text into the question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I disabled TDR and it works now. Thank you!